# SSRS : Data Driven Subscriptions Auto Increment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have Data Driven subscriptions which run @ 8 AM on reports and it creates PDFs based on CustomerID.
Below are the few PDF filenames : (Each file has the customer ID appended to the filename, In this case, 12345 and 45678 are the customer IDs for both files)

SampleReport_11_12345

HighlightedReport_9_45678

So, The next day if the same Customer ID (12345 and 45678) report is generated, the file names are being changed like

SampleReport_11_12346

HighlightedReport_9_45679

Next day I want to change the file names as

SampleReport_11_12345_1

HighlightedReport_9_45678_1

It's adding a number to CustomerID, Do you know how to resolve this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you running this in SharePoint? What are your current settings for the file name? Do you have separate subscriptions for each customer?

Comment: It sounds like you are dropping the file in the same location and the number is being incremented to prevent overwriting. There should be some option in the subscription like *Increment file names as newer versions are added* that you should deselect or add a @TimeStamp to the name.

Comment: Are you using Standard or Enterprise version? If Enterprise, you can build the file name based on a query.. if standard.. you can append a data or tick the auto increment check box so it won't overwrite and append the 1 or 2 as you want

Comment: Added time stamp to the filename, it helped.